# Is it possible to serialize NDSolveValue results for use in other notebooks?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, files-and-directories

I would not be surprised if this has already been addressed and I am overlooking it somehow.

I have a fairly long running `NDSolveValue[]`. I am developing a post-processing graphic. Is it possible to serialize and unserialize results from `NDSolveValue`?

My thought is that I would serialize the results into a binary file that contains the $$\{IntepolatingFunction_1,InterpoltatingFuntion_2\}$$ result from `NDSolveValue`.  I could then load the results into a standard Mathematica list and proceed to work on the post-processing graphics (without waiting for another run of `NDSolveValue`).

This would also allow me to load the results in separate notebooks.

Comment: Does `g = NDSolveValue[...]; DumpSave["file.mx", "g"];` do what you need? You can retrieve the interpolating functions with ```<<file` ```

Comment: I am giving this a try.

Comment: I usually like `Export` better than `DumpSave` for this purpose: `res=NDSolveValue[...]` and then `Export["file.mx",res]`. Loading will then be done with: `loadedres=Import["file.mx"]`. It has the advantage that it does not overwrite any variables and you don't need to remember what variable was used when `DumpSave`-ing the result. You can also export several results to one file, e.g.: `Export["results.mx",{res1,res2,res3}]

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.  This allows me to keep different notebooks for different visualizations of the same PDE.